# C: ignoring a comment line in input file

Tags: c, input, line

im using the fscanf function to handle input. now in the input each line starting with a # must be ignored. how do i ignore a complete line? for example this input:

```
#add some cars
car add 123456 White_Mazda_3 99 0
car add 123457 Green_Mazda_3 101 0
car add 111222 Red_Audi_TT 55 1200

#let see the cars
report available_cars

#John Doe takes a white mazda
customer new 123 JohnDoe
customer rent 123 123456

#Can anyone else take the mazda?
report available_cars

#let see Johns status
report customer 123
```

as you see the comments may vary in length and the commands are varying in their structure... is there some way to distinguish between two lines? or a way to tell when we are at the end/start of a line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of using `fscanf()`, read lines with `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` to replace the `fscanf()`.

```
char s1[13], s2[4], s3[17], s4[43];
char line[1000];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    if (*line == '#') continue; /* ignore comment line */
    if (sscanf(line, "%12s%3s%16s%42s", s1, s2, s3, s4) != 4) {
        /* handle error */
    } else {
        /* handle variables */
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is that we are not allowed to use fgets() in our assignment because it causes memory leaks and security issues...

Comment: @Yanal: huh? Are you perhaps speaking of `gets()`? `fgets()` is very very easy to use safely (like in my answer) preventing memory leaks or security issues.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Are you sure you're not confusing `fgets()` with the broken `gets()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()` for line-oriented input instead of free-form input.

Comment: the thing is that we are not allowed to use fgets() in our assignment because it causes memory leaks and security issues...